# How to get difference of two date in same column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

How can I get the time difference of the two same date in the same column? And what if there is multiple in/out in the same day?

Table `tbl_Employee_MasterList`:

```
id  First_Name       Last_Name    biometric_no
----------------------------------------------
125 ABRAHAM JOSEPH   MOQUETE           78
```

Table `officer_timelogs`

```
employee_id      record_time             Day      type
--------------------------------------------------------
125         2018-02-27 18:03:31.000    Tuesday     1
125         2018-02-27 07:54:03.000    Tuesday     0
```

SQL query:

```
select 
    a.employee_id, a.record_time, 
    --CONVERT(char(10), a.record_time, 103) as [Date],
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, a.record_time) as [Day],
    a.[type],
    case 
       when a.[type] = 0
          then 'in'
       when a.[type] = 1
          then 'out'
    end as Status
from
    officer_timelogs a
left join 
    tbl_Employee_MasterList b on a.employee_id = b.biometric_no
where 
    a.employee_id = '125'
order by 
    a.record_time desc
```

Output:

```
employee_id record_time               Day       type    Status
---------------------------------------------------------------
     125    2018-02-28 07:47:23.000 Wednesday   0        in
     125    2018-02-27 18:03:31.000 Tuesday     1        out
     125    2018-02-27 07:54:03.000 Tuesday     0        in
     125    2018-02-26 18:01:59.000 Monday      1        out
     125    2018-02-26 07:48:25.000 Monday      0        in
     125    2018-02-24 12:50:00.000 Saturday    1        out
     125    2018-02-24 07:44:16.000 Saturday    0        in
     125    2018-02-23 17:02:06.000 Friday      1        out
     125    2018-02-23 07:48:26.000 Friday      0        in
     125    2018-02-22 18:02:35.000 Thursday    1        out
     125    2018-02-22 07:48:41.000 Thursday    0        in
```

Desired output (I want to retrieve data like this):

```
employee_id    Date         Day       Hours
-----------------------------------------------------
   125         2018-02-27   Tuesday   10:09:28 (h:m:s)
```

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Learn how to ask question!!!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is my first time to ask question here, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Please use text instead of images. Add your existing query into this question, and paste in some sample data. Everything seen on that image should be text in the question. Also learn how to format there is a small icon that looks like this `{}` in the edit toolbar, use that to format for code or data

Comment: thanks. I already edited my question.

Comment: @AJMoquete, that's not enough. Provide some sample data including *multiple in/out* and expected output from that

Comment: @Uzi How can I calculate time that spent for the day?

Comment: @AJMoquete, I can not help if you don't provide sample data. You are keeping editing expected output. But you should show how your tables look like. What datas are in it. And then what output you expect from them

Comment: @Uzi i want to retrieve data like written in Output. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Uzi I finalized my question.

Comment: @AJMoquete. That's much better. But clarify several things please. 1. What if there will be two consecutive `ins` without corresponding `out`. Like for 2018-02-28 you don't have `out` value. 2. Why do you need here `tbl_Employee_MasterList` if you don't getting data from this table

Comment: @Uzi 1. if there's multiple, my plan is to get the first in and last out when calculating the hours.Then if there's no in/out I will mark as absent. 2. To determine the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used one table to simplify. I t will not be hard to join and get emplyee names. This query calculates time difference between first in and last out as you asked. And returns '00:00:00' if either in or out is missing

```
declare @t table (
    employee_id int
    , record_time datetime
    , type int
)
insert into @t 
values (125, '20180228 07:47:23.000', 0)
    , (125, '20180227 18:03:31.000', 1), (125, '20180227 07:54:03.000', 0)
    , (125, '20180226 18:01:59.000', 1), (125, '20180226 07:48:25.000', 0)
    , (125, '20180224 12:50:00.000', 1), (125, '20180224 07:44:16.000', 0)
    , (125, '20180223 17:02:06.000', 1), (125, '20180223 07:48:26.000', 0)
    , (125, '20180222 18:02:35.000', 1), (125, '20180222 07:48:41.000', 0)

select
    employee_id, [date]
    , [hours] = right(concat('00', diff / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('00', diff % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('00', diff % 60), 2)
from (
    select
        employee_id, [date] = cast(record_time as date)
        , diff = datediff(ss, min(iif(type = 0, record_time, null)), max(iif(type = 1, record_time, null)))
    from
        @t
    group by employee_id, cast(record_time as date)
) t
```

But I recommend to look at this query. It calculates each in-out times separately and then gets total sum per day

```
select
    employee_id, [date]
    , [hours] = right(concat('00', diff / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('00', diff % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('00', diff % 60), 2)
from (
    select
        employee_id, [date] = cast(isnull([in], [out]) as date)
        , diff = sum(diff)
    from (
        select
            employee_id, [in] = max(iif(type = 0, record_time, null))
            , [out] = max(iif(type = 1, record_time, null))
            , diff = datediff(ss, max(iif(type = 0, record_time, null)), max(iif(type = 1, record_time, null)))
        from (
            select
                *, grp = sum(iif(type = 0, 1, 0)) over (partition by employee_id order by record_time)
            from
                @t
        ) t
        group by employee_id, grp
    ) t
    group by employee_id, cast(isnull([in], [out]) as date)
) t
```